# Вход по логину и паролю в БД T-SQL в программе c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Здравствуйте! Есть необходимость входа в программу по логин и паролю. Слышал, что отдельная таблица не подходит с целью улучшения безопасности. Как это можно осуществить?

Comment: Наилучшим вариантом будет сделать сессию, при присутствии back-end. Так же можно запрашивать пароль при действиях пользователя. Что вы имеете в виду под отдельнай таблицей? Где вы хотите это хранить, как не в базе?

Comment: Я думал сделать отдельную таблицу в которой хранился бы логин и пароль. Но т.к. я понял, это не безопасно потому, что таким образом мы получаем доступ к базе данных раньше, чем пользователь вводит логин и пароль. Мне говорили необходимо создать отдельного пользователя в СУБД и из под него заходить. Как обычно делаете вы?

Comment: Вашей ценной информацией является пароль, которой всегда шифруется (хэшируется). И делаете это каждый раз, когда пользователь вводит пароль - для сопоставления. Вот статья - [Шифрование C#](https://habrahabr.ru/post/254909/)

Comment: А чем не годятся штатные средства MS SQL - не вошел  в базу,  нет доступа к элементам формы, кроме кнопки "выход".

Comment: Любую программу можно взломать, ваша главная цель - не допустить несанцнианированного доспута к данным. Для этого сервер всегда должен понимать, имеет ли данный пользователь права на выполжения данного действия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартная трёх уровневая архитектура.

1. Программа клиент.
2. Бизнес логика и код на сервере, предоставляющая (Web API, Rest, WebService) для доступа программе.
3. База данных на сервере.

Схема работы такая:

По умолчанию программа может только вызывать функцию `bool TryLogin(string username, string password)` если пользователь залогинелся то в сессии, либо более современный способ в JWT токене хранится информация о пользователе, из которой можно получить его права.

Дале для каждой операции сначала идёт проверка прав, есть ли у данного пользователя права для выполнения данной операции. Если прав нету то выдаётся ошибка.

Таким образом к базе данных имеет доступ только тот пользователь, который авторизован для данной операции, кроме того доступ идёт не к самой базе данных а к API который предоставляет сервис (2-ой уровень).

То есть права на конкретные операции определяются пользователем который сейчас залогинен.

Пользователь никак не может получить таблицу с паролями, так как
1. Этого не позволяет API системы.
2. Любые операции делаются под конкретным пользователем с конкретными правами.

Кроме того пароли на сервере обычно хранят в зашифрованном виде, на случай если кто-то всё-таки умудрился получить доступ к базе, например через exploit или нечестный админ на сервере.

В ручнею нету необходимости всё это создавать с нуля, для этого есть много разных готовых библиотек. В случае с C# есть например Identity.